# Installing react gives the following error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, installation, npm-install, npx

First, I make this globally, then I install my app.
Then I go to my project directories. Finally, when I am running the project it shows the error illustrated in the image below.
I have tried so many thing like uninstalling `node.js` then reinstalling again or  deleting node module(s), etc. What more do you think, should I try? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Project is running at http://192.168.0.101/

Comment: please write what command you use to install react ? did you make it form scratch or using create-react-app

Comment: using creating-react-app but i got my solution thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the react-script version to 2.1.8. 

  `npm install react-scripts@2.1.8 
  npm start`

Package json dependencies should get updated to

```
"dependencies": { 
    ------------------
    ---------------------
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"  
 },
```

Comment: @MahamodulShakil please upvote and mark it as correct one